# Unable to parse JSON using Guide Template Language

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, gtl

I have a Json Input string , while parsing the Json the Description field  value is breaking into another line, why this line is breaking

```
%%[
    var @Json
    set @Json = '{
        "ArticleCount": 22,
        "Description": "<Content><fig id=\"ehx401-F1\" orientation=\"portrait\" position=\"float\"><label>Figure 1</label><caption><p>Causes of hospital readmission by timing of occurrence. Distribution of causes of hospital readmission according to the timing of their occurrence since discharge after the procedure. (From Franzone A, Pilgrim T, Arnold N, Heg D, Langhammer B, Piccolo R, Roost E, Praz F, Räber L, Valgimigli M, Wenaweser P, Jüni P, Carrel T, Windecker S, Stortecky S. Rates and predictors of hospital readmission after transcatheter aortic valve implantation. See pages: 2211–2217).</p></caption><graphic orientation=\"portrait\" position=\"float\" href=\"ehx401f1.tif\" /></fig></Content>"
    }'
]%%

{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxrows=20}}
    {{.data}}
        {"target" :"@json" }
    {{/data}}
    ArticleCount:{{ArticleCount}}<br/>
    Description:{{Description}}<br/>
{{/datasource}}
```

**Output is displaying like:**

Causes of hospital readmission by timing of occurrence. Distribution of causes of hospital readmission according to the timing of their occurrence since discharge after the procedure. (From Franzone A, Pilgrim T, Arnold N, Heg D, Langhammer B, Piccolo R, Roost E, Praz F, Räber L, Valgimigli M, Wenaweser P, Jüni P, Carrel T, Windecker S, Stortecky S. Rates and predictors of hospital readmission after transcatheter aortic valve implantation. See pages: 2211–2217).

ArticleCount:22
Description:Figure 1

Actually the Description Value should have to come after Figure1, but it is displaying at the top,How to Rectify this mistake?

Comment: Try reversing the order in your code?

Comment: I meant declaring article count before decision value. Might yield the intended results

Comment: Why do you have two usernames?

Comment: 'If i am not declaring the article count, i am displaying description field value only, but again same output is coming @Data_Kid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use your code, I see that the order appears correctly.

I suspect the issue that you are experiencing is related to your XML, as you are using unsupported HTML elements:

- `Content`
- `fig`
- `graphic`
- `caption`

**caption is a supported HTML element, but only in tables and must be inserted immediately after the `<table>` tag.*

Also their respective attributes such as `orientation` and `position` are unknown to the User Agent and is causing unexpected results when you display them.

I would recommend:

1. Removing the unsupported `orientation` and `position` attributes
2. Change `content`, `fig` and `caption`* to a supported element, like `div`
3. Change `graphic` to `img`

You may also want to consider writing an XSL template to transform the XML to supported HTML and use this in conjunction with the AMPscript [TransformXML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/transformxml.htm) function.

Comment: ,How to use  TransformXML function for description value in this scenario can you guide me the code @Eliot Harper

Comment: Hello, please understand SFSE is not a code writing service. If you are unfamiliar with XSL, there are many resources available online.

Comment: ok sorry, thank you for giving valid answer for this question@Eliot Harper

Comment: I have another doubt,set Json = '{
        "ArticleCount": 22,
        "Description": "<Content><fig id=\"ehx401-F1\" orientation=\"portrait\" position=\"float\"><label>Figure 1</label>"},{
        "ArticleCount": 22,
        "Description": "<Content><fig id=\"ehx401-F1\" orientation=\"portrait\" position=\"float\"><label>Figure 1</label>"
    }',if json input values is repeatedly coming same value, i want to iterate the same process, how @Eliot Harper,can  you guide me for this scenario

Comment: I assume you would like to loop through and display objects in an array. I've created an example which does this (just copy the code and preview any Subscriber and you will see it working). [Download the example html here](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/7d185625077a57d5ce081bb58c275290).

Comment: ,what i need to give here - {{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxrows=20}}
    {{.data}}
        {"target" :"@json" }
    {{/data}}
    ArticleCount:{{ArticleCount}}<br/>
    Description:{{Description}}<br/>
{{/datasource}}

i checked your link, which i have to download, whether i have to use each variable in object@ Eliot Harper

Comment: i dont want entire scenario, just what i need to change {{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxrows=20}} {{.data}} {"target" :"@json" } {{/data}} ArticleCount:{{ArticleCount}}<br/> Description:{{Description}}<br/> {{/datasource}}  from here for iterating the loop@Eliot Harper